# Free newsletter software for a small business?

Tags: gratis, email, newsletter

I am looking for free software that has the following features:

- Send mass mails
- Organize subscription lists
- Use HTML (with or without templates)
- Analytics
- Schedule e-mails

For instance, [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/) is an online web service which has these features, but it is not free.

Comment: FYI, MailChimp now has a free tier of service: http://mailchimp.com/pricing/ .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Highly recommend [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com)!

I have been using this website for the past year and I have not found a fault yet. All the requirements you need are met with the free version. I used most if not all the features and would be able to explain them in more detail if needed.  Here are the features:

Create

- Email Beamer
- Email Designer
- Email Templates
- Integrations
- Merge Tags
- Multi-User Accounts

Manage

- Custom Forms
- Segmentation and Groups
- Subscriber Profiles

Deliver

- Autoresponders
- Spam Filter Diagnostics
- Email Delivery
- Geolocation
- Email Client Testing
- RSS-to-Email
- Delivery by Time Zone

Analytics

- A/B Testing
- Reports

Mobile

- Coupon Codes
- MailChimp Editor
- MailChimp Mobile
- Mobile Signup Forms
- SMS for Events
- VIP Subscribers

Share

- Campaign Archives
- Social Pro
- Social Sharing

Free accounts come with:

- Up to 2,000 subscribers
- Send 12,000 emails to 2,000 subscribers for free. No contracts, and no credit card required. It’s free forever.

A few examples of the emails I've sent:

- [An email where I added all the facebook content from my page over the last month and sent it to a selected group which don't have access to facebook (which was a question when they subscribed) automatically every month](http://eepurl.com/Nx1wb)
- [An email I sent to all lists to enrol members into our club conference.](http://eepurl.com/G8TdL)
- [Just a standard e-news I send out](http://eepurl.com/Gvlp5)

Comment: I would recommend Mailchimp as well.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the free version of [reachmail](http://www.reachmail.net) which allows you to send 15.000 emails/month.

- Schedule e-mails
- Analytic - This gives a wide rand of views/charts on what was clicked/opened within an email broadcast
- Template designer
- Mailing list

Answer (score 4):

I'm using [phplist](https://www.phplist.org/), a self-host Free Software mailing program. (They also offer a [hosted service](https://www.phplist.com/) on a [freemium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemium) model.)

To address your requirements:
It's designed for sending individual mass mails, it organises the subscribers in several lists, you can use a graphical editor for creating your (HTML) mails, it provides analytics such that you can see the response rate and response time, and which links were clicked.  You also have the option to schedule e-mails.

[image: list of campaigns]

[image: subscribers]

[image: stats]

Answer (score 3):

If you want something that integrates tightly with gmail try http://flashissue.com. You can:

- design emails,
- use HTML templates,
- build mailing lists from google contacts and
- view performance reports

Answer (score 2):

If you need a self-hosted solution, I recommend this: http://sendy.co.

It's not free, but since it uses Amazon SES you can send emails 10x cheaper than Mailchimp and others.

Comment: Please be more specific about your recommendation. Did you use it? What are your experiences? What are its pros and cons? We prefer our answers to be full fledged personal recommendations rather then a a name and a link that "could work". Have a look at [this meta](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/94).

Comment: Sendy is not 10x cheaper than $0 for a small business using mailchimp.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this one is quite old question, but I've just started using mailerlite and thought that those who would look for such solution as Anastasios should take a look at it. 
It's very user friendly web app and has free plans (unfortunately limited). Even if you won't fit within given amount of subscribers /emails it's a very cheap solution if compared with others as mailchimp etc.

Comment: Please be more specific about your recommendations. What are your experiences with mailerlite? What are its pros and cons? We prefer our answers to be full fledged personal recommendations rather then a name that "could work". Have a look at [this meta](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/94).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this mass mailer - https://www.massmailsoftware.com/bulkmail/ it has all features that you need, but isn't free( full version costs $35, it's don't need monthly fees).