# Hosted app for a family newsletter

Tags: hosted, mailing-list, newsletter

Here's a related question about small business newsletter management, a use case I'm sure overlaps somewhat with strictly social newsletters: [Free newsletter software for a small business?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/55/free-newsletter-software-for-a-small-business)

And here's a good, recent overview of newsletter apps: https://zapier.com/learn/ultimate-guide-to-email-marketing-apps/best-email-newsletter-software/

But I'm wondering if there are any clear winners for people who are not using this for marketing.

Here are some hard and soft requirements:

- Allow collaboration on lists with partner
- Basic templating (e.g., include a standard footer with website login info so I don't have to remember to type it in every time, and avoid data entry errors)
- Ability to group list members
- Import Gmail contacts
- Sync with Gmail contacts

[MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com) seems great, and we do qualify for their free tier of service, but it isn't quite as lightweight as I'd prefer.  For example, I can't just log in and quickly send an e-mail announcing a website update.  I tried their new [TinyLetter](http://tinyletter.com), which is also great, but that permits no templating, and the "subscribers" cannot be grouped.

Comment: It sounds like MailChimp may be your best bet, but how many people do you have on your list? It also sounds like you're open to a paid solution but would prefer free if possible?

Comment: @ZeroFlux that's true.  I'd prefer free but am open to paid for a price that's reasonable for personal use.  My list is about 100 members right now.